# PdfReader iText is slow or I receive Java heap exception for large files

Tags: itext, large-files, pdf-reader, pdfstamper

I ran the following logic for various files, here are the times to execute:

125Mb ~ 90 seconds

250Mb ~ 5.5 minutes

500Mb ~ 18 minutes 45 seconds

Is there something wrong with my logic here that it takes so long?

Was previously creating PdfReader with the bytes from the file, but was getting java heap space exception using that.

Any ideas to improve the speed/capacity would be appreciated.

```
String filename = "C:\\Temp\\500Mb.pdf";
RandomAccessFileOrArray r = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filename);
PdfReader main = new PdfReader(r, null);
File outputFile = new File("C:\\Temp\\outputFile.pdf");
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
    PdfStamper stmpr = new PdfStamper(main, output);
    PdfWriter writer = stmpr.getWriter();
    writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines); //Set bookmarks to open
    stmpr.close();
}
```

Comment: How much memory have you assigned to your Java VM running the code?

Comment: Difficult to tell with the amount of information you provide...

Comment: -Xmx2048m I have tried more, does not speed it up

Comment: Upping it does allow me to process up to a 1Gb file (using the in memory option, code not shown here), but that is the limit for the in memory option, I cannot get it to process 2 Gb file no matter what I set it to.

Comment: Can you share the test files in question?